# Ejecutar tarea programada en windows

Tags: laravel, windows, cron

Hola hice una tarea programada que ejecuta un .bat el cual tiene las instrucciones para ejecutar un comando de artisan (laravel).

Esto es lo que tiene el bat.

```
C:\www\php\php.exe artisan schedule:run
```

Si ejecuto el bat directamente si ejecuta bien lo que necesito.

Si lo ejecuta la tarea programada no pasa nada.

Tienen alguna idea de porque pasa esto.

Ya le di privilegio al archivo, agregue a everyone y le di todos los permisos. Ya hice que la tarea se ejecutara en el grupo de trabajo y tampoco hace nada.

Este es el task

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2019-05-16T20:53:23.4943963</Date>
    <Author>DESKTOP\Trabajo</Author>
    <URI>\laravel ejecutar</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2019-05-16T21:10:12</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-2952428836-490331607-3802055516-1001</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\www\htdocs\Orion\ejecutar.bat</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay Cinco opciones:

1. Crea un acceso directo del .bat y manda a correr el acceso directo en la tarea programada.
2. Por mi experiencia, comprueba el usuario que ejecuta la tarea programada. Yo una vez habia puesto el administrador del dominio y no me hacia caso, añadi el usuario del pc con  privilegios elevados en el que ejecutaba la tarea y funciona ok.
3. Ve a Administración de Equipos: Servicios: Programador de Tareas: Propiedades_ Iniciar sesión: Cuenta Local: Permitir que el servicio interactúe con el Escritorio.
4. Crear un vbs para correr el bat:

   `Dim objWsh Set objWsh = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) objWsh.Run "C:\Path\MyCMDScript.bat" , 0 , 0 Set(objWsh)=Nothing`

Y cambiar `C:\Path\MyCMDScript.bat` por la ruta completa de tu bat.

5. Colocar `/b` para indicar que no se debe ejecutar todo en la misma línea. (Gracias @AlbertoOrtega !)

Suerte!

Comment: Gracias, no era el usuario. Solo me faltaba poner /b creo que es para indicar que no debe de ejecutar todo en la misma linea.